# Prove that every nonconstant polynomial either increases or decreases without bound

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Prove that every nonconstant polynomial either increases or decreases without bound.

I was wondering if the above were true, and if it were, is it possible to show that if $P(x) = a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$, then $|P(x)| > x$ for sufficiently large $x$ if $\text{deg}(P) \geq 2$?

Comment: Consider $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{|P(x)|}{x}$.

Comment: @sranthrop What about the first question?

Comment: You just have the (algebra-precalculus) tag on your question. Do you have the tools of calculus at your disposal?

Comment: Also, a non-constant polynomial just requires that $\deg (P) \geq 1$, not 2.

Comment: @erfink Are both statements true?

Comment: In general we have that for any polynomial $p$ there are numbers $a,b>0$ such that $|p(x)|\geq ax^n$ for $x\geq b$, where $n\geq 0$ is the degree of $p$.

Answer (score 0):

Derivative $f'(x)$  of a polynomial $f(x)$ is again a polynomial. 
 Now by induction on the degree of a polynomial we can try to prove it.
True for linear polynomial.(straight lines extend to infinity).  For higher degree polynomial, use fundamental theorem of calculus, area under a curve keeps increasing if the function keeps increasing; if the derivative keeps decreasing no problem absolute value of area keeps increasing.

Answer (score 0):

If $x>1$ then $x^n>1$. Thus, for $x>1$, $P(x) = a_n x^n + \ldots + a_0 \geq a_n x^n + a_{n-1} + \ldots + a_0$.

If $a_n>0$, we will show that $P(x)$ tends to infinity as $x$ tends to infinity. Fix $c> \max(a_n+\ldots+a_0,0)$. Then, you can show that there exists an $x_0>1$ such that $a_n x^n + a_{n-1} + \ldots + a_0 \geq c$ for all $x>x_0$ ( you can calculate $x_0 = ((c-a_{n-1} - \ldots - a_0)/a_n)^{1/n}$. Thus, $P(x) \geq c$ for all $x > x_0$. Since we can make $c$ arbitrarily big, $P(x)$ must be able to be made arbitrarily big.

You can do a similar argument for $a_n <0$.

As for $|P(x)|>x$ for sufficiently large $x$, it depends. If you have $P(x) = x/2$, this is clearly false. However, note that for $a,b>0$,  $a x^n \geq  bx$ for $x> (b/a)^{1/(n-1)}$, and you can other similar statements for different sign choices of $a,b$ and direction of inequality to show that $|P(x)|$ will eventually be bigger than $|x|$ for a degree >=2 polynomial.